# Canon GP-E2 GPS error on Canon 7d

Tags: canon-7d, gps

I started using a GPS logger on my 7D during a trip and had great luck in the first couple days. Halfway during the trip, the camera would completely freeze and display an error. This would happen when trying to store the image onto the CF card. Before snapping a picture, the camera's menu would not recognize the GPS unit.

Does anyone have an idea as to what could cause this? I've since switched to log mode and disconnected the unit to tag later.

Comment: What firmware have you got installed on the 7D?

Comment: Was using 2.0 at first, and then tried with 2.0.3 and still encountered the same problem.

Comment: I don't have direct experience of this. But I'd try a different CF card just to rule that out.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've previously had issues due to the climate damaging gear I've taken on trips. 
Where about did you travel to? Humidity often does the most damage but any extremes such as heat or cold are more than capable of destroying the accessories. The cameras themselves are somewhat more hardy and if your only experiencing issues when the GPS logger is attached, it again suggests the camera is fine.

If it was working fine and you didn't change anything, it likely failed on its own accord. This could be a good reason to get a replacement unit under warranty.

Hope it helps.

Comment: It was likely a faulty unit. I rented, but borrowlenses refunded my rental once it was sent back. The trip was to Yellowstone. Hot and humid time of year.